# PHP socket alternate listen/connect

Tags: php, sockets

I have built a small PHP server/client code. When I say client server I mean it acts bought as client and a server alternating for 5 seconds in each mode.

Now the code runs on two servers and is triggered by a cron.

On rare occasions they manage to get in perfect sync with each other and they either establish a connection at the very last microsecond but by then the PHP code has already passed to the client mode or they never manage to establish a connection.

Before this whole dance starts they run some database queries to select some information that can be big or small and never identical on them so adding some randomness in the timings has only made this incidents happen more rarely but not disappear completely.

Anyone ever manage to do something like this successfully? How?

Comment: This is probably way to lightweight for us to help. What's the difference between the server and the client? What is it for? If you want this to work, without mixing of the two processes - I suggest each code schedule the next server/client process. So when the server completes its operation, you schedule the client process - and when the client process is done you schedule the server process.

Comment: Bought trigger the same process. Sending the selected data to the other. And because I do not want one to be server and the other client cause at some stage there will be more then one server in play.

Comment: When two servers connect to each other they exchange the data and disconnect then continue the same with the next server on the list and so on until the list of servers to exchange data with is empty.

Comment: Having one as server and the rest as clients would cause the whole exchange process to go down if the server goes down. If a server is down and cannot be contacted after set no of attempt's to connect it is considered offline and process skips it.

Comment: There is external communication. Multiple servers. Each does a specific thing but they need once in a while to share the data with each other. SYNC (NO, A DISTRIBUTED DATABASE IS NOT AN OPTION)

Answer (score 1):

You have designed a [***race condition***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here. No matter how you try to synchronize these, you'll get in trouble eventually.

The way to solve this is to have each process acting as a servere all the time, and doing client functionality on demand.

Comment: Tried that. First thing I tried. Same issue. On occasion two servers would connect to each other's server part but them being in the on demand client part and just hanging there waiting for the other to respond until timeout. and then the cycle begins again. Tried with a small random sleep period. Still same thing. Unless I somehow disengage the server part without closing as closing causes on occasion the inability to rebind to the same port. P.S. Yes I have set the option to reuse addr.

Comment: You are just confusing yourself here. Define your workflow, draw the state transition diagram, states, events - all the good stuff. You'll probably find that you don't need this strange setup.